# Cannot get two background images extending entirety of page?

Tags: html, css, layout

here is the layout im trying to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wu73.jpg

I have a repeating swatch of the background that is set to the html's background so the grey paper tecture repeats beyond the design.

Then i Have the bamboo illustration that goes on top of that set to the background of the body.

I cant seem to get the bamboo to not be cut off to where the content ends.

What is the best possible way to do this?

the white content div in the center needs to extend down to at least the bottom of the page, and i cant for the life of me figure this out it seems like it has to be the simplest thing to do

this is what it looks like now- https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWIa5.png

here is the code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
html{
background:url(images/background_swatch.png) top center;
}

body{
margin:0 auto;
background:url(images/background.png) top center no-repeat;
}


div#wrapper{
margin:0 auto;
width:800px;
background-color:#FFF;
border-left:5px solid black;
border-right:5px solid black;
}

#header{
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
top:25px;   
background:url(images/navigation_banner.png) no-repeat;
width:850px;
height:150px;
left: -25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to what you want to change...Could you post your code?

or which do you want to extend, because it seems to me like the bamboo picture is all the way down, if you want it further, maybe stretch it further (height:120%;) ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height 100% on html container, min-height on body container.

http://jsfiddle.net/5FwGZ/

```
html { 
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://imjustcreative.com/wp-content/uploads/ImJustCreative-2010-08-23-at-06.06.01.jpg');
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.landscapecreationsfl.com/flower-dahlia-pink-transparent-background-350_1_.gif')
}
div#content {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
}
​
```

Comment: i tried this, but whenever the content on the page goes further than tha initial 100% the image is cut off. For example, if my initial browser height is something 600px, if i have say 800px worth of content the extra 200px i have to scroll down to see will have the bamboo design cut off at the original 600px line